# What is the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{3^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What I got figured out is that I should pair up $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}$ giving me $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{3})^{n}(-2n-1)$. I know that the first part converges to $\frac{3}{4}$, but the other part is divergent. How should I proceed?

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k}=-\frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\Rightarrow\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k+1}=-\frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}}
 $$ $$\Rightarrow\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(2k+1\right)x^{2k}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{x^{3}}{1-x^{2}}\right)
 $$ then take $x=1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Okay, I'm on level with everything you said there. Can you explain why this is, though?
$$\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k}=-\frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}$$

Comment: @Radu It is the sum of a geometric series. Note that in your case the series starts from $1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Okay, I suspect that the formula comes from
$\sum_{k\geq0}ar^{k}=\frac{a}{1-r}$
and if I were to take your case, r would be $x^2$, and a would be $(-1)^k$. But if exchanged into the result, it doesn't add up to what it should.

Comment: @Radu In the proof $r=-x^{2}$ and $a=1$. Again note that the series in the proof starts from $1$, not from $0$.

Comment: I understand now. I was missing the part that the sum was starting from $0$. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Radu You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

prove by induction that your finite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{3^n}=3/8\, \left( -1/3 \right) ^{k+1}+3/2\, \left( -1/3 \right) ^{k+1}
 \left( k+1 \right) +5/8
$$ and compute then the limit for $k$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: But how would he conjecture that specific expression?

Comment: i have found this sum in my old book there is a collection of such sums

Comment: Irrelevant. After all these comments on some similar posts of yours, you still do not get why the infinite sum is often simpler than the finite sums? To top it all, you do not even know why the identity for the finite sums hold but "have found this sum in (your) old book there is a collection of such sums"? Sorry but this is the opposite of what mathematics is about.

Comment: Enlightening ^^

Answer (score 0):

Express $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{3^{n}}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n+1)\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n$$ and use the formula for the arrthmetico-geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(an+b)r^n=\frac{b}{1-r}+\frac{ar}{(1-r)^2}\quad (|r|<1).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{3^{n}}=\underbrace{3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{3^{n+1}}-\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{3^{n}}\right)}_{1}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n} n$$

On the other hand if $|x|<1$ then 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
in othere words
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
set $x=-\frac 13$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(-\frac 13\right)^n =-\frac{3}{16}$$